# Error compiling jsp files using ant from gradle

Tags: ant, gradle, build.gradle, jasper-plugin

I'm getting an error when i try to execute a custom gradle task to pre-compile jsp files.
My task looks like:

```
task compile_jsp(dependsOn: 'compileJava') << { 
    //Define master classpath
    def masterpath = ant.path(id: 'master-classpath') {
        fileset(dir: "${rootDir}/build/libs"){
            include(name: '**.jar')
        }
        fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir) {
            include(name: '**/*.class')
        }
        fileset(dir: "${rootDir}/src/main"){
            include(name: '**/*.java')
        }
    }

    ant.taskdef(classname: 'org.apache.jasper.JspC', name: 'jasper', classpath: configurations.jasper.asPath + masterpath)
    ant.jasper(uriRoot: "${rootDir}/src/main/webapp/", outputDir: "${rootDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/" + "${compileJspOutputDir}/", webXmlFragment: "${rootDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml", addWebXmlMappings: "true")
}
```

The error that i get is something like:

```
The value for the useBean class attribute <class> is invalid.
```

I think its related to the classes location in the project because the task works well if i define the `sourceSets.main.output.classesDir` like:

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir = "${rootDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"
```

Otherwise, i get the mentioned error.

Is there any way to run this without change the classes dir?

Comment: To me it sounds more like Jasper is complaining about an incorrect `generated_web.xml`.

Comment: Hmm if so, why it works if i set the classesDir to "WEB-INF/classes" path? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure, you might want to find out where this output is coming from. I don't even understand why you'd want to change the `classesDir` of the main source set. BTW: The [Tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin) has a built-in task for executing Jasper. It does all the wiring for you.

Comment: But i don't want to change the `classesDir`. I only changed it because all the threads i've seen about this problem say that classes must be located inside `WEB-INF` folder and for now its the only way it works. I didn't know this tomcat plugin, but tanks for the advice ;)

Comment: My question is: Must the `classes` folder be necessarily located within the `WEB-INF` folder?